# This person's question was closed for incorrect reasons, and is compliant if the people that closed it knew the answer

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, close-reasons

In reference to this closed question: [How to anonymously donate cryptocurrency to charities which only support traditional online payments platform?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/135125/how-to-anonymously-donate-cryptocurrency-to-charities-which-only-support-traditi/135126#135126)

The reason for closing this question was that it is offtopic because it requires an off site resource that would change quickly.

This is not correct because the universe of answers do not require that, and assuming they do seems to be based in ignorance and trepidation around anonymous financing, which isn't necessarily what the question is about. As anonymous has multiple contexts in the non profit world.

Neither of those concerns change reality that this is an answerable personal finance question that fits the moderation guidelines of this site.

I've incorporated benign uses of cryptocurrencies in personal finance questions and answers since 2013 or so, and it is clear that there is a general anathema towards cryptocurrencies in personal finance forums. It is also clear that the consensus has shifted towards the realities I presented nearly a decade ago, which the same and different people with high reputation disagreed with when I originally presented them. This is another one of those, and I also have worked with non-profit lawyers, tax lawyers and various kinds of registered charities regarding cryptocurrency.

[How to anonymously donate cryptocurrency to charities which only support traditional online payments platform?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/135125/how-to-anonymously-donate-cryptocurrency-to-charities-which-only-support-traditi/135126#135126)

Needs several more reopen votes.

Edit: three reopen votes obtained, I think two more necessary.

Edit to bump: four votes obtained. When I think about the active people on this site there aren't really that many, 5 of them had voted to close, 4 additional including myself have voted to reopen, so I'm really not sure how many interested parties there are here.

Comment: I believe it needs two more votes to reopen. I'm not sure how many it takes, I think it is 5 though.

Comment: One more vote needed, thanks for looking.